# How to make a chrome extension that opens a popup menu with multiple buttons that open links in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a simple chrome extension that pops open a menu of buttons that all lead to links that are opened in new tabs, but haven't had any luck.

Here is the code I have so far.

Thanks for the help in advance!

popup.html

```css
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NGN HUB</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
    <h1>NGN HUB</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonA">
        <p><button type="button" id="twitch" onClick="location.href='http://twitch.tv/newbgamingnetworks/'">NGN Twitch Channel</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonB">
        <p><button type="button" id="website" onClick="location.href='http://newbgamingnetworks.wix.com/newb-gaming-networks'">NGN Website Link</button></p>
        </div>
    <div id="buttonC">
        <p><button type="button" id="donate" onClick="location.href='http://newbgamingnetworks.wix.com/newb-gaming-networks#!donate/c1er4'">NGN Donation Page</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonD">
        <p><button type="button" id="twitter" onClick="location.href='http://www.twitter.com/NewbgamingN/'">NGN Twitter Account</button></p>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright © NGN 2016

</body>
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/51/3e/4f/513e4f5274ec48f29b894b0b8409658f.jpg");
    }
    #header {
        background-color:rgb(96, 222, 72);
        text-align:center;
        padding:1px;
    }
    #footer {
        background-color:rgb(96, 222, 72);
        clear:both;
        text-align:center;
        padding:1px;
    }
    #buttonA {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #buttonB {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #buttonC {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #buttonD {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #twitch {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color:blueviolet;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color: #FFF;
    }
    #twitch:hover {
        color: blueviolet;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:blueviolet;
    }
    #website {
        color:black;
        background-color:rgb(96, 222, 72);
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:black;
    }
    #website:hover {
        color:rgb(96, 222, 72);
        background-color:black;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:rgb(96, 222, 72);
    }
    #donate {
        color:black;
        background-color:rgb(0, 193, 204);;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:black;
    }
    #donate:hover {
        color:rgb(0, 193, 204);
        background-color:black;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:rgb(0, 193, 204);
    }
    #twitter {
        color:white;
        background-color:rgb(0, 152, 255);
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:white;
    }
    #twitter:hover {
        color:rgb(0, 152, 255);
        background-color:white;
        border-width:3px
        border-color:rgb(0, 152, 255);
    }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Clarification would help us, and help you avoid having your question downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [chrome.tabs documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) there is a full overview with examples for your issue.

Just to make things a little bit more clear, you should add the "tabs" permission in your manifest, and then the chrome.tabs api will be available to you, when that will happen you will be able to query, open and close chrome tabs.

for example:

`chrome.tabs.create({url: "your site url"});`

**How to subscribe to on-click event**

First I must say that there are plenty of ways to do it, the way I'm suggesting here is definitely not the best practice, but just the easy way doing it with vanilla js. (get you started)

```
<button type="button" id="website">NGN Website Link</button>

<script>
var button = document.getElementById("website");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Your code goes here.
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "your url"});
});
</script>
```

I hope that helps, but any way you should have a look at jQuery\Angular.. or any other framework that might help you.

Comment: I'm having two main problems. A. when I load in the extension and click the link buttons they don't go to the link. B. I am unsure how to open the links in a new tab,

Comment: My original answer was about B. I will try to edit my original answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the help with B. all I need now is to figure out how to put the open tab code into the button.

Comment: Have a look now, if you find the answer helpful please mark it as the right one.